Next js Loader is only showing page load time but not showing for page/navigation changes for server side render component
Server side rendering page:

export default async function page({
  searchParams
}) {
  
  const orders = await getData(searchParams.page);
    return (
        <main className="flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center justify-between p-24">
        <div className="z-10 max-w-5xl w-full items-center justify-between font-mono text-sm lg:flex">
        <CTable data= {orders}/>
        </div>
         <Pagi pages={10}/>
       </main>
    )
}

Table code it is also server side component for rendering data:
export default async function dataTable({data}) {
  const orders = await data;
  
  const orderRendering =orders ? orders.items.map((order) => {
     return <div className="flex text-left">
          <div className="m-10 w-10">{order.id}</div>
          <div className="m-10 w-40">{order.date}</div>
          <div className="m-10 w-40">{order.customer}</div>
          <div className="m-10 w-30">
            <button  className="mr-5 border border-blue-500 px-4 py-2 rounded-md text-white bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-600 focus:outline-none focus:border-blue-700 focus:ring focus:ring-blue-200 active:bg-blue-700 transition">EDIT</button>
            <button className="border border-blue-500 px-4 py-2 rounded-md text-white bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-600 focus:outline-none focus:border-blue-700 focus:ring focus:ring-blue-200 active:bg-blue-700 transition">DELETE</button>
          </div>
     </div>
  }): "";

  return (
    <div>
         <div className="flex text-left">
          <div className="m-10 w-10">ID</div>
          <div className="m-10 w-40">Date</div>
          <div className="m-10 w-40">Customer</div>
          <div className="m-10 w-30">Actions</div>
        </div>
        {orderRendering}
       
    </div>
  )
}

pagination client component code:
"use client"
import { useState } from "react";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';
import {Pagination, PaginationItem, PaginationCursor} from "@nextui-org/react";

export default function Pagi({pages}) {
    const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
    const router = useRouter();
    useEffect(() => {
        router.push("/orders?page="+page);
    },[page]);

    return (
        <Pagination
        isCompact
        showControls
        showShadow
        color="primary"
        page={page}
        total={pages}
        onChange={(page) => setPage(page)}
      />
    );
}

folder structure:
..........
orders
 --loading.js
 -- page.js

Loader is not showing when I change pagination. I have used sleep 10 secs for api backend but it wait 10 secs but not showing just wait.

Remove the use state hook, and make this a server component. Then the search params will be passed in as props, assuming you're using at least Next v13, and then change that onChange method to a navigation method. If you're using a pagination library I'm almost positive that they'll allow you to set the button href yourself, and if you're doing this without a library just change those buttons to be Next Links. That would be something like:
export default function Pagi({searchParams:{page = 1}}) {

    return (
        <Pagination
        isCompact
        showControls
        showShadow
        color="primary"
        page={page}
        total={pages}
        onChange={(page) => {
/// NOTE: replace this with href on each button. You'll have to look at the docs for @next-ui/org to figure out exactly what property that would involve, but it's not `onChange`.
    window.location.href = `/yourPage?page=${page}`
}}
      />
    );
}


it is working but I want without page reload the loader will be shown for page changes. Is it possible. if not possible why?

If you're using Next's native Link element the new page will automatically be shown in the background, but this is the ideal approach to avoid sending more data to the client than they need to speed things up. But again, try and replace the onChange method with a way to wrap the buttons in a Link element. It looks like you can provide a renderItem function and use that to wrap the button in a Next.js Link component to automatically pre-fetch the pages content.
